# How to create a column of unique IDs to match an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing table in SQL Server which looks like the below, it is a list of comments in a conversation with multiple users. ID is the incrementing PK and ConversationSet identifies the comments in a specific conversation. This table holds MANY different ConversationSets.

| ID | Name | Comment | ConversationSet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | "I'm more of a dog person." | 17 |
| 2 | Jay | "Excuse me?" | 17 |
| 3 | Sam | "What?" | 17 |
| 4 | Jay | "I'm going to block you" | 17 |
| 5 | Anon | "This is another convo" | 18 |

I would like to know if there is a way to add a secondary unique ID column which will help identify the speaker throughout the conversation. E.g. I would like to create a column which will set an ID for Sam throughout the conversation, and a different ID for Jay throughout the conversation.

| ID | Name | NameId | Comment | ConversationSet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 42 | "I'm more of a dog person." | 17 |
| 2 | Jay | 40 | "Excuse me?" | 17 |
| 3 | Sam | 42 | "What?" | 17 |
| 4 | Jay | 40 | "I'm going to block you" | 17 |
| 5 | Anon | 63 | "This is another convo" | 18 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       rank() over (partition by conversationset order by name) as name_id
from t;
```

If you want the same id across all conversations for a given name, then remove the `partition by`.

If you want gapless numbers, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by conversationset order by name) as name_id
from t;
```

Comment: @st3lz . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?